# Can I have a template helper only run once in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have a template that looks like this:

```
<template name="foo">
  <div id="wrapper" style="overflow: hidden">
    <div id="content" style="margin-top: -{{contentHeight}}px">
      {{content}}
    </div>
    <button id="toggle">Show/Hide Content</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

where `{{contentHeight}}` is a helper that calculates the height of `#content`, and clicking the toggle button causes `#content` to slide up/down by animating its margin.

The problem is that when I do a database update on `foo`, `#content`'s `style` attribute is reset with the new `contentHeight` value, hiding it. I don't want Meteor to touch the element once it's rendered, but even giving it a unique ID doesn't prevent that; as the docs say:

> Meteor will preserve [elements with unique names/IDs] even when their enclosing template is rerendered, but will still update their children *and copy over any attribute changes.*

(Emphasis mine.) So what's the best approach? How do I set the element's `style` when the template is rendered, then prevent Meteor from modifying the attribute?

Comment: I assume that you want the height to be set _before_ rendering so that using `Meteor.defer` is out of the question?

Comment: @TomColeman Right. I know I could use a `setTimeout` hack, but there are several reasons not to (efficiency, flicker, potentially invalid calculations elsewhere in my script...).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
<div id="content" {{contentHeightStyle}}>

Template.foo.contentHeightStyle = function() {
  if (!this._contentHeightStyleCalculated) {
    this._contentHeightStyleCalculated = true;
    return 'style="..."';
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, but it doesn't work. After fetching an update from the server, `this` is a completely different object. As far as I can tell, Meteor lacks a mechanism for storing local state corresponding to models. I could store my own hash using `this._id` as keys, of course, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Also, even if that weren't a problem, returning `undefined` from the helper would still overwrite whatever the `style` attribute was...

Comment: Ok: a way of getting around the first problem is to do something like `Session.set('heightCalculated-' + this._id, true)` etc. The second part has stumped me I must admit.